# My Angular application doesn't hit breakpoint when debugging?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi, vscode-debugger

Kinda new to Visual Studio Code and Angular applications with a C# Web API back-end. No problem hitting a breakpoint in C#, just not hitting it in Angular app in VS Code!

I can run both apps just fine the in the browser, from the terminal, with `dotnet run` and `ng serve` **BUT** when I hit the debug button to debug my app, Angular breakpoints go from red to hollow grey!

**Disclaimer** - I have to mention that I changed lots of the file names and renamed the .csproj file because I wanted the app to reflect my name and not the one the instructor used. Before I did this, I was able to set breakpoints and hit them in the Angular app.

Here is what I've tried.

1. restarted VS Code
2. ng start, ng serve
3. generated a new launch.json file (auto-generated by VS Code) in the same folder level that contains my two project folders (Ng, .Net)
4. removed my workspace file (can't seem to generate a new one, not sure if I need to)

In the file:

> error.interceptor.ts

I'm trying to test this exception handling by saying:

```
throw new Exception("Some login error");
```

in my Login method.

I can set a breakpoint shown below but it becomes a grey circle and never gets hit when I click Debug.

[image]

Here is where I set the breakpoints

[image]

Here is what I see when running the debugger, the red circles become grey and hollow. I'd like to be able to step through this error interceptor when debugging, is this possible?

[image]

and then in my login method from my angular app, my breakpoints become grey

[image]

Here is my launch.json file

```js
{
  // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
  // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
  // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Yogabandy.API.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy.API",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "launchBrowser": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also - I'm seeing a lot of these lines when I run the debug console. Don't know if this is normal?

> Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.4/System.Threading.dll'. The module was built without symbols.
>   Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.4/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. The module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: Are you happy to debug in chrome?

Comment: seems like you are starting the dotnet debugger

Comment: Markus. I would say 'yes' I think? But can't I step through the typescript code from the Angular app in VS Code when debugging? Or is the whole debugger part just for dotnet stuff? Maybe I'm loosing my mind, but I thought that at some point in an earlier part of the tutorial the instructor stepped through and hit breakpoints in VS Code from the Angualar app

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_debugging-angular

Comment: Avin. Yes, I've installed the debugger for Chrome extension

Comment: add the line `debugger;` where you want to break execution.

Comment: You'll find it's much easier and more powerful just to debug the Angular stuff in Chrome. The developer tools are built in - just hit F12 with the Chrome window active. Go to the sources tab and look for the source code files, then you can debug in the built-in debugger.

Comment: I was hoping he would discover that himself when he added the `debugger;` line :)

Comment: Ok, so why did I have to add 'debugger;' to a line in the ng app!? Because now that I've done that, it breaks on a breakpoint! I even removed the 'debugger;' line and it still breaks on a breakpoint! Weird! But the breakpoint that gets hit is from a readonly file that has the same name as the real file with the breakpoints. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: dubugger is the old way to break execution in a web browser, now you can put a dot next to a line. Seems like everything is working as expected?

Comment: Hi Chris. Just curious, I opened up the Chrome debugger and looked for any file that resembles, say, "app.component.ts", but don't see anything. Where would this be in the source area in the debugger?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's what was going on! It has to do with the path to the project in the .vscode file and the need to debug two separate project/s folders at one time!

> ${workspaceFolder}

I have two folders for the app

1. Yogabandy-SPA (Angular app)
2. Yogabandy.API (ASP.Net Core Web API)

I thought the best place for the .vscode file was at the root level, and unless someone has a better solution this seems to be the best place.

[image]

But the problem is the path of the workspace folder needed to be corrected.

Corrected paths

```js
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}" // old
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy-SPA" // new
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Yogabandy.API.dll" // old
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Yogabandy.API.dll" // new
```

```js
// removed from the 'server' command so two debuggers don't open, just one
"serverReadyAction": {
  "action": "openExternally",
  "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
},
```

Added a compound so that I could debug both projects together.

```js
"compounds": [{
  "name": "Server/Client",
  "configurations": ["server", "client"]
}]
```

I'm still having a minor issue starting the debugger. VS Code displays this below, but I am able to now debug both apps together and hit all breakpoints from both projects.
[image]

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

```js
"compounds": [{
  "name": "Server/Client",
  "configurations": ["server", "client"]
}],
"configurations": [{
    "name": "server",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Yogabandy.API.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy.API",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "env": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
      "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "client",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Yogabandy-SPA"
  }
```

Comment: Senin Allahina kurban

Comment: Just remove the line `"preLaunchTask": "build"` and the error "Could not find task 'build'" will go away.

Comment: This was helpful. In my case, I was using "ng build --watch" and serving with gin-gonic (Go lang). The trick for me was to add "-c development" to my "ng build" cmd line to get debug info.

Answer (score 23):

Just in case this was not helpful, I had the same problem, just because of wron angular.json configuration

```
"development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
```

without this configuration, it's handled like production and You are not able to stop at breakpoints.

Comment: At angular.json, but which level?: root?, inside architect? or wut...

Comment: @zameb it works in architect:build:configurations

Answer (score 12):

It seems you haven't configured chrome debugger extension in `launch.json` file. from [vscode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_configure-the-chrome-debugger):

> We need to initially configure the debugger. To do so, go to the Debug view (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and click on the gear button to create a `launch.json` debugger configuration file. Choose Chrome from the Select Environment drop-down list. This will create a `launch.json` file in a new `.vscode` folder in your project which includes a configuration to launch the website.
>
> We need to make one change for our example: change the port of the url from **8080** to **4200**. Your `launch.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or the green arrow to launch the debugger and open a new browser instance. The source code where the breakpoint is set runs on startup before the debugger was attached so we won't hit the breakpoint until we refresh the web page. Refresh the page and you should hit your breakpoint.

Comment: Use 'chrome debugger' and put 'debugger' in the code (the function, where you want to debug) , this will hit the code without break point.

method () {
debugger 

...
}

Comment: While that indeed works it's not the ideal solution, the breakpoints should work on their own without debugger statements.

Answer (score 10):

I also searched for hours...

Somehow after updating my angular-cli (To 12.2.5) and some packages i could not debug with "ng serve" anymore. I always had unbound breaking points.

I fixed it using [Collins Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67704997/16935272) and additionally adding the following under "serve": in angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
   "development": {
      "browserTarget": "<YOURAPPNAME>:build:development"
   }
},
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
```

Comment: This with @Collin solution worked for me! I don't know if defaultConfiguration will break something though

Comment: @boludokid  yeah I'm wondering the same thing.  Will it interfer when building in production?

Comment: @boludokid I ended up commenting out the 'defaultConfiguration' line and running 'ng serve --configuration=development'.  I also mapped it to the package.json scripts section, so now it's just 'npm run start:dev'.

Answer (score 4):

Mine, even being in the same folder as the project, only worked by including '/ src' in $ {workspaceFolder}.

Folder Directory

[image: Folder Directory]

launch.json configuration

[image: launch.json configuration]

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who is looking for a quick fix try this:

make sure your port number in the Launch.json settings is same as the one you get after "ng serve" command. usually it is "4200" and try to include both launch and attach settings in Launch.json.

once "ng serve" is completed and angular server started listening try to click "start debugging"

then the debugger will lauch a chrome instance on 4200 and after that you can see the break point will be bound.

Do not launch it manually by typing the link(http://localhost:4200/) in browser

Answer (score 1):

I searched for days and it finally made sense.
First like others before me, you want to make sure that you are **already** running the client with 'ng s'/'ng serve', **only after** you do this should you try to run and debug.

You also want to make sure the debugger will be listening in on the right port. Not only that, but you want to check if your url in the browser matches the url in the launch json, if its https:// or just http://

Next you want to make sure you are in the right webroot directory, so the debugger knows where to check for your angular client. So just like @tiagorockman went through, you need to have the webroot navigate to the client folder itself. If you have a task.json in your .vscode folder, then  you might want to do the same like so

[This image shows you where to change the cwd for the directory to the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBn1Y.png)

If you want to take a look at my launch.json, its nothing special but here it is.
[my launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXMaZ.png)

You can check this link for more information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-sMmxfNxBMhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535916/my-angular-application-doesnt-hit-breakpoint-when-debugging

Lastly, there is the possibility that the browser you are using has a CORS blocker enabled. You can disable this for development purposes only by adding an extension and following their tutorials. The one I used was https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino/related?hl=en

I hope this helped. Feel free to ask if you want more clarification, and I can see what I can add to help. I use this answer whenever I am using a new machine or onboarding one of my juniors. I think this is relevant with the [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) [debugging](/questions/tagged/debugging) topics as well

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting Angular debugging to work in VS Code. Turns out it was Node.js.

If you run:

```
ng --version
```

and see this:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.6
Node: 18.12.1 (Unsupported)
```

Then you need to downgrade node to 16.6.0.

This solved it for me. Angular 15 will support node 18.* but Angular 14 does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on Stackoverflow and might be the same problem for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72792138/5517161

basically run your application with `ng serve --host=127.0.0.1` and magically you can debug.

Make sure your `development settings` in your angular.json are correct, your chrome launch settings is `localhost:4200`

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration in serve section in angular.json file to this:

```
"configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "browserTarget": "your-app-name:build:production",
                        "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js"
                    },
                    "development": {
                        "browserTarget": "your-app-name:build:development"
                    }
                },
"defaultConfiguration": "development",
```