# When I lunch chrome debbuger my breakpoints are not visible

Tags: angular, debugging, angular15

IDE Visual studio CODE

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Uruchom przeglądarkę Chrome względem hosta lokalnego",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

sourcemap: true, standard chrome configuration, various things, still points are not reacheable.
I would like to debug my code before lauching chrome breakpoints are red, but after lauching they are grey.

Answer (score 0):

ng serve --host=127.0.0.1

with explicitly telling ng to run app on host 127.0.0.1, making debugger run without errors and breakpoints are read correctly.

[Suddenly gets Could not read source map in VSCode using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203399/suddenly-gets-could-not-read-source-map-in-vscode-using-angular)