# vscode returns unbound breakpoint when I try to initialize debug mode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

i have a project in angular, and when i try to initialize debug mode and put some breakpoints, vscode returns unbound breakpoints
node version 18.15.0
angular CLI 15.1.6
angular 15.2.1
Npm 9.6.2
OS win32 x64

[image: 1]

the tsconfig sourcemap is true.

is this a compatibility issue between angular and node?

Comment: Have your configured to output sourcemaps? Do you need to set the `outFiles` field of your launch config? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging#_mapping-the-output-location "_If generated (transpiled) JavaScript files do not live next to their source, you can help the VS Code debugger locate them by setting the outFiles attribute in the launch configuration._"

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i already solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, apparently it is a problem of the ipv6 protocol of the localhost and the version of the node.
more information in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75563264/21046260

Comment: see also the answer I just added there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75784584/11107541