# VS Code PWA Chrome/Edge Angular webpack map files are not loaded anymore

Tags: angular, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, webpack-dev-server, vscode-debugger

Breakpoints in my Angular projects are not "bound" any more.
There is no obvious reason for this, since there weren't any changes to the project.
What might has changed are the versions of the browsers - to this matter I have no control since they are managed by the IT-department of my organization.

What if found so far, lead to the conclusion the map files are not loaded any more.

[Diagnostics output (no map files)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx9Yq.png)

I can open the map files by accessing the directly for example like this:
`http://localhost:4200/main.js.map`

My launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "msedge",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            // "trace": true
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

First Chrome stoppt working and a day later Edge.
Any ideas what could have changed, probably a setting in the browsers?

I can still set a breakpoint in the Browser DevTools/source (in the ts-source) and this breakpoint will be synchronized with VSCode, but not with the actual ts file, it only binds to the js package.

[SourceMap is available in the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw2ZS.png)

Thanks
Dominik

**What I found out:**

While I was searching for a solution I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203399/).

As suggested I added following to launch.json:

```
         "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/**",
             "!**/node_modules/**"
         ],
```

This removed the warnings about loading the source files really slow.
But it also prevented the other suggested solution "ng serve --host=127.0.0.1" to work.
Took my a while to figure this out.

So, without "resolveSourceMapLocations" section and the "--host" paramter the breakpoints are bound again.

But still can't explain what triggert this problem.
I guessing a mix up between ip4 and ip6.

("ping localhost" returns [::1] - even our Network doesn't use IP6 adresses)

My env:

- "NODE_OPTIONS=--dns-result-order=ipv4firs"
- VSCode: 1.82.2
- Chrome: 117.0.5938.63
- Node.js: 18.18.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: You can try other browsers to see if the same problem occurs, such as brave, firefox, etc. If you still need to use chrome and Edge, I recommend reporting this issue via [this llink](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). You can temporarily roll back their versions to keep them working.