# Cannot Debug Angular 15 app in VS Code on Windows

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging

I upgraded an existing project to Angular 15 and now I can't debug: "Some of your breakpoints could not be set".

On clicking "troubleshoot your launch configuration" against the unbound breakpoint, and then "Why don't my breakpoints bind", I see

"We couldn't find a corresponding source location, and didn't find any source with the name app.component.ts."

plus

"Make sure you have "sourceMap": true in your tsconfig to generate sourcemaps."

But this is already the case:

```json
    "sourceMap": true,
```

Other StackOverflow solutions suggest the same: [Debug with Visual Studio Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443217/debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working)

I've restarted VS Code, rebooted the PC, re-installed global Angular cli (15.0.4) and created a completely new project. I still can't hit a breakpoint.

This post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535916/my-angular-application-doesnt-hit-breakpoint-when-debugging/67704997#67704997:~:text=Angular%20CLI%3A%2014.2.6%0ANode%3A%2018.12.1%20(Unsupported)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535916/my-angular-application-doesnt-hit-breakpoint-when-debugging/67704997#67704997:%7E:text=Angular%20CLI%3A%2014.2.6%0ANode%3A%2018.12.1%20(Unsupported)) advises node 18.12.1 is unsupported for Angular 14, but on viewing my Angular version there's no warning that node v18.12.1 is unsupported by Angular 15

```json
    Angular CLI: 15.0.4
    Node: 18.12.1
```

Another suggestion is to append src to the workspaceFolder against webroot in launch.json https://stackoverflow.com/a/63730484/1830758 but that hasn't resolved the issue

As this has been reproduced against a new project after reinstalling global Angular CLI, I guess the unmodified config would have to be correct and I must have some other environmental issue?

Comment: workaround: use browser sources tab for now if you need immediate debugging capabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging can be restored by downgrading Node to v16.19.0

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, I downgraded the Node to 16.19.0 as you said and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Angular CLI: 14.2.13
Node: 16.20.2
Package Manager: npm 8.19.4 
OS: win32 x64
I have the following versions but not working for me

Answer (score 2):

[Why am I suddenly getting "Could not read source map" in VSCode using Angular with NodeJS 17 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203399/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-could-not-read-source-map-in-vscode-using-angular-wi)
solved it exactly. Issue was with node 18. This allowed me not to have to downgrade.

change your serve command to `ng serve --host=127.0.0.1`